# Conjunctive regex matching tokens in Java

Tags: java, regex, string

I have a large `List<String>` where each String is a sentence containing 1+ "tokens" (prefixed by "a" or "b" and followed by a positive integer):

```
List<String> tokenList = new ArrayList<String>()
tokenList.add("How now a1 cow.")
tokenList.add("The b1 has oddly-shaped a2.")
tokenList.add("I like a2! b2, b2, b2!")
// etc.
```

I want to write a function that accepts a vararg list of tokens and will return a subset of the `tokenList` of String that contain **all** the token arguments. For instance:

```
public class TokenMatcher {
    List<String> tokenList; // Same tokenList as above

    List<String> findSentencesWith(String... tokens) {
        List<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        // Build up the regex... (TODO: this is where I'm going wrong)
        for(String t : tokens) {
            sb.append(t);
            sb.append("|");
        }

        String regex = sb.toString();

        for(String sentence : tokenList) {
            if(sentence.matches(regex)) {
                results.add(sentence);
            }
        }

        return results;
    }
}
```

Again, the regex has to be constructed in such a way that **all** the `tokens` passed into the function have to exist inside the sentence in order for the match to be true. Hence:

```
TokenMatcher matcher = new TokenMatcher(tokenList);
List<String> results = matcher.findSentencesWith("a1");     // Returns 1 String ("How now a1 cow")
List<String> results2 = matcher.findSentencesWith("b1");    // Returns 1 String ("The b1 has oddly-shaped a2.")
List<String> results3 = matcher.findSentencesWith("a2");    // Returns the 2 Strings with a2 in them since "a2" is all we care about...
List<String> results4 = matcher.findSentencesWith("a2", "b2");  // Returns 1 String ("I like a2! b2, b2, b2!.") because we care about BOTH tokens
```

The last example (`results4`) is important because although the "a2" token appears in several sentences, with `results4` we are asking the method to give us matches for sentences containing **both** tokens.  This is n-ary conjunctive, meaning that if we specified 50 tokens as parameters, we would only want sentences with all 50 tokens.

The above `findSentencesWith` example is my best attempt so far. Any ideas?

Comment: Would it help you to combine [lookaheads](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) for being independent of the order of matches? To get a match of any strings which contain anywhere `a2` and `b2` and `c2` it would be: [^(?=.*a2)(?=.*b2)(?=.*c2)](http://regex101.com/r/lM6wI8/1). Well, possibly not, what you need ;)

Comment: Thanks @Jonny5 (+1) - sure that sounds fine, but I still don't see how it all comes together (perhaps you can post an answer with a complete code example?). I don't care about order, or frequency (that is, if I can `findSentencesWith("a2")` I don't care if a sentence contains 1 instance of `a2` or 100,000 instances of it). Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given your stated requirements that neither order nor frequency matter, I don't see the need to use *regexes* at all in this case.

Rather, you can compare every string with all the example tokens that were provided and see if all are contained in the string. If so, it's in the result set. The first time a missing token is detected, that string is removed from the result set.

This sort of code would look something like this:

**TokenMatcher.java**

```
package so_token;

import java.util.*;    

public class TokenMatcher {

    public TokenMatcher(List<String> tokenList) {
        this.tokenList = tokenList;
    }

    List<String> tokenList;

    List<String> findSentencesWith(String... tokens) {
        List<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();

        // start by assuming they're all good...
        results.addAll(tokenList);

        for (String str : tokenList) {
            for(String t : tokens) {
                // ... and remove it from the result set if we fail to find a token
                if (!str.contains(t)) {
                    results.remove(str);

                    // no point in continuing for this token
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        return results;
    }

    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        List<String> tokenList = new ArrayList<String>();
        tokenList.add("How now a1 cow.");
        tokenList.add("The b1 has oddly-shaped a2.");
        tokenList.add("I like a2! b2, b2, b2!");

        TokenMatcher matcher = new TokenMatcher(tokenList);

        List<String> results = matcher.findSentencesWith("a1");     // Returns 1 String ("How now a1 cow")

        for (String r : results) {
            System.out.println("1 - result: " + r);
        }

        List<String> results2 = matcher.findSentencesWith("b1");    // Returns 1 String ("The b1 has oddly-shaped a2.")

        for (String r : results2) {
            System.out.println("2 - result: " + r);
        }

        List<String> results3 = matcher.findSentencesWith("a2");    // Returns the 2 Strings with a2 in them since "a2" is all we care about...

        for (String r : results3) {
            System.out.println("3 - result: " + r);
        }       

        List<String> results4 = matcher.findSentencesWith("a2", "b2");  // Returns 1 String ("I like a2! b2, b2, b2!.") because we care about BOTH tokens

        for (String r : results4) {
            System.out.println("4 - result: " + r);
        }
    }
}
```

This results in the following output:

```
1 - result: How now a1 cow.
2 - result: The b1 has oddly-shaped a2.
3 - result: The b1 has oddly-shaped a2.
3 - result: I like a2! b2, b2, b2!
4 - result: I like a2! b2, b2, b2!
```

Slightly tweaked, runnable code (mainly around no package name and non-public class, so it'll run on the site) on [ideone](http://ideone.com/RlgTq3).

**Note:** Based on the information you provided, and since the function is accepting a list of tokens, it appears that `contains` would be sufficient for determining whether or not the token is present. However, if it turns out there are additional constraints on that, such as the token must be followed by a space or one out of a set of punctuation, or something like that, in order to count as a token, then I *would* recommend using *regexes* -- on an individual-token basis -- replacing `contains` with `matches` and passing in the *regex* defining what you want surrounding the token.

It may also be desirable to have a function that validates your `tokenList` that is passed to the `findSentencesWith` function.